# How to get the selected option from p:selectOneRadio using javascript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectoneradio

How do you get which radio is selected  within `p:selectOneRadio` using javascript/jquery ?

Since the `p:selectOneRadio` uses no radio tags I have no idea how to get the checked option using CSS selectors.

```
    <p:selectOneRadio onchange="reactToChangedRadio()" >
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry for the created confusion due to lack of time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jquery solution or choose a simple javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById("myFormId:mySelectId")[0].checked
```

See the post from CodeRanch: http://www.coderanch.com/t/210871/JSF/java/selectOneRadio-javascript-value

UPDATE:
I must admit that I'm in a dept, and I'm sorry for that but yesterday I haven't had much time...

I must say that I haven't been able to get the radio value in the old fashioned javascript way:

```
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                      /*  <![CDATA[ */

                        function reactToChangedRadio(){
                           alert("I'm in!");
                           var myval;
                            for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                                    if(document.forms['myFormId']['myFormId:myRadio'][i].checked == true ){
                                        myval = document.forms['myFormId']['myFormId:myRadio'].text/value;
                                    }
                                }
                                alert( "val = " + myval );
                        }
                    /*    ]]> */
                </script>
```

On the other hand, this hard-coded solution works:

```
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                      /*  <![CDATA[ */

                        function reactToChangedRadio(){
                           alert("I'm in");
                           var myval;
                           if(document.forms['myFormId']['myFormId:myRadio'][0].checked == true ){
                              myval = "first button";
                           }else if(document.forms['myFormId']['myFormId:myRadio'][1].checked == true ){
                              myval = "second button";
                           }else if(document.forms['myFormId']['myFormId:myRadio'][2].checked == true ){
                              myval = "third button";
                           }

                           alert( "val = " + myval );
                        }
                    /*    ]]> */
                    </script>
```

,but of course, because of Primefaces power, there is a server side solution(using ReuqestContext component):

```
                 <h:form id="myFormId">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="myRadio" value="#{handleFiles.radioVal}" >
                            <p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" listener="#{handleFiles.testMethod}" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue=" first" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue=" second" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue=" third" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
    alert("Selected Radio Value" + args.myRadVal);  
 } 
</script>
```

The server side code:

```
private String radioVal;

public String getRadioVal() {
    return radioVal;
}

public void setRadioVal(String radioVal) {
    this.radioVal = radioVal;
}

public void test(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    context.addCallbackParam("myRadVal", radioVal);
    System.out.println("radioVal: "+radioVal);
}
```

the ReuqestContext component can be found here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf (only for PF 3)

Comment: This doesn't return the checked value. This only returns whether the item itself is checked or not.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, my bad, it should contain a for loop and instead the zero should be the iterator variable...

Comment: to get the checked item, what to iterate over & how?

Comment: Just iterate over radio buttons which you got from the DOM. You might want to reframe your question to leave JSF out the context and post only the JSF-generated HTML markup code (and retag the question) so that JS/jQuery users can help you more easy.

Comment: @BalusC I've updated my answer, sorry for the created confusion due to lack of time...

Comment: @Marcos Please tell me if there is something you didn't understood or if your problem isn't resolved...

Comment: @Marcos which solution? have you tried the `RequestContext`? I must admit that this is my favorite :)

Comment: @Spauny: Actually I used `$element[0].value` to directly get the value of chosen radio, where `$element` was passed using `this` from `p:selectOneRadio`'s `onChange`. I wanted to avoid putting any code for view within the beans, so chose this way... and it seemed neat too. Thanks a lot for your great help, anyways... :)

Comment: private String radioVal; is found in other package, but you need keep "private" how you can do it?

Comment: @delive How can `radioVal` be private when it needs to be accessible by the selectOneRadio component? You have to have a getter and a setter for it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think is the best, with  context to get/capure values checked, that create a javascript function. But thanks =

Answer (score 6):

The problem could be solved easily with jquery find() by using getJQ method of the pf widget:

```
<p:selectOneRadio ... widgetVar="mySelectName" .../>
```

we can obtain current value by calling:

```
PF('mySelectName').getJQ().find(':checked').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the value of selected item in JS you can call your function with `this.value` parameter.
Look inside PF generated HTML:

```
<input id="{component_id}:{index}" name="{component_id}" type="radio" value="{itemValue}"
    checked="checked" onchange="reactToChangedRadio(this.value);">
...
```

for each `selectItem`.
Hence `this.value` works perfectly, no need to search for `checked`:

```
<script>
    function reactToChangeRadio(par){
        alert('Value of selected item is: ' + par);
    }
</script>

<p:selectOneRadio onchange="reactToChangedRadio(this.value);" >
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="....." itemValue="..." />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Or you can pass `this.id` into function to use it in jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

you have yo use the **:checked** pseudo selector:
More info here: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
 $(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to disable all radio buttons except the one that was checked like:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="rad" ... onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this)" >
  <f:selectItems .... />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

And here is your script:

```
function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio){
      var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
      var temp = radio.name.lastIndexOf(':') - 1;
      var index = radio.name.substring(temp,temp+1);
      var el = radio.form.elements;

       for(var i = 0 ; el.length; i++)
       {
          if(el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
              if(el[i].name.indexOf(index) != -1)
                  el[i].check = true;
              else
                   el[i].check = false;

           }
       }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-line solution to this question that also handles the case where you have multiple selectOneRadio inputs on a page.

If your form is called `myForm`, and your selectOneRadio input has the id `myRadio`, then the following line will get the selected value:

```
$('[id^=myForm\\:myRadio]:checked').val()
```

This works because all the internal inputs are given an id beginning with `myForm:myRadio`. The line above finds all entities beginning with that string, and selects only the checked ones. Since only one radio button can be checked a a time, this gives the selected radio button. Then we can simply grab its value.